# Python: How to keep region inside canny close edge's area

Tags: python, python-3.x, edge-detection

I'm using canny algorithm to find the edges.

Next, I want to keep the region inside the closed curves.

My code sample is:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import scipy.ndimage as nd
from skimage.morphology import watershed
from skimage.filters import sobel

img1 = cv2.imread('coins.jpg')
img = cv2.imread('coins.jpg',0)

edges= cv2.Canny(img,120,200)

markers = np.zeros_like(img)
markers[edges<50] = 0
markers[edges==255] = 1
img1[markers == 1] = [0,0,255]
img1[markers == 0] = [255,255,255]

cv2.imshow('Original', img)
cv2.imshow('Canny', img1)

#Wait for user to press a key
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

My output image is [image]

I want to show the original pixels values inside the coins. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use an union-find structure to get the connected components of white pixels of your img1. (You might want to find the details of this algorithm on Wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure).

Once you have the connected components, my best idea is to consider the conected components that do not contain any point on the border of your picture (they should correspond to the interior of your coins) and color them in the color of img.

Sure, you may have some kind of triangles between your coins that will still be colored, but you could remove the corresponding connected components by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. The coin outlines are not continuous so that any kind of filling will leak.

You can repair the edges by some form of morphological processing (erosion), but this will bring the coins in contact and create unreachable regions between them.

As a fallback solution, you can try a Hough circle detector and mask inside the disks.